# IP Address of servers

Tags: sockets, ip

So I am kind of new to networking and I'm just interested in the client/server architecture. Let's say you developed a program and the client version ran on a computer and the server version on the server(obviously). In order for the client to connect to the server, it would have to know the ip address of the server (and the port attached so it can be routed to the correct computer/program). Does that mean that the server's ip address can not change? Would you have to specifically tell your ISP to keep the ip address static? Because if both the client and server ip addresses change, then they would have no way to connect and the program wouldn't work... in other words there has to be one constant. When you sign up for a VPS do they give you a static ip address you can bind to from the client version? Thanks!

Comment: You use the server *name* in the code, or make it configurable at the client.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: What do I mean by what? 'Name'? 'Configurable'?

Answer (score 1):

> In order for the client to connect to the server, it would have to know the ip address of the server (and the port attached so it can be routed to the correct computer/program).

Correct.

> Does that mean that the server's ip address can not change?

No. In fact, IPs can change at any time.  Most servers that are exposed to the public Internet have a static domain name registered in the Internet's DNS system.  A client asks DNS to resolve the desired domain name to its current IP address, and then the client can connect to it.  But even in private LANs, most routers act as a local DNS server, allowing machines on the same network to discover each other's IP by machine name.

The OS typically handles DNS for you.  A client can simply call `gethostbyname()` or prefferably `getaddrinfo()`, and the OS will perform DNS queries as needed on the client's behalf and return back the reported IP(s).

> Would you have to specifically tell your ISP to keep the ip address static?

You can, but that usually costs extra.  And it is not necessary if your server is registered in DNS.  And there are free/cheap DNS systems that work with servers that do not have a static IP.

> Because if both the client and server ip addresses change, then they would have no way to connect and the program wouldn't work...

That is where DNS comes into play.

> in other words there has to be one constant.

A registered domain name that can be resolved by DNS.

> When you sign up for a VPS do they give you a static ip address you can bind to from the client version?

It depends on the VPS service, but a more likely scenario would be you are assigned a static sub-domain within the VPS service's main domain. For example, `myserver.thevps.com`. Or, if you buy your own domain (which can be done very cheaply from any number of providers), you can usually link it to the DNS server operated by your VPS service.